# Change Objective function on Decision tree

Tags: r, cart, decision-tree

I'm trying to build a binary decision tree and only selecting nodes with a concentration of 75% (or greater) of target (Yes vs. No)

Only those whose nodes with 75% or greater will get the treatment.

Is there a method to change the decision tree objective to maximize the number of observations with at least 75% Yes (or some other number)?

I can mock up some code if that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want your decision tree to predict an outcome being greater than 75%? If so, create a column that is true when the target column is `>.75` and use that column as the outcome

```
df$newOutcome <- df$oldOutcome > .75
```

Comment: I believe that'll give me the nodes that are greater than 75%.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to create nodes with at least 75% accuracy. My goal would be the most observations with at least x% accurate.